# SCCM PowerShell Get Configuration Baseline computers

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am working with Configuration Baselines.  I would like to start from "Get-CMBaseline -Name MyBaselineName" and work my way to the name of the machines. I am try to figure out how to get the machines names that are "Compliant", "Error", and "Non-Compliant".  I see the names of the machines in "Deployment Status" but I need them via PowerShell.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It's sounds like you want us to write the code for you. This is not how SO works.

Comment: this is probably only possible with wmi and not a cmdlet, is that an option?

Comment: I would perfect ok with WMI if that was possible.  I would be ok with SQL because I could port it into powershell.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat There is a understanding from Microsoft that if you can click on it then you can Powershell it.  SCCM has over 500+ commandlets and most are not documented well.  I have dug through the top 100 commandlets from SCCM but Configuration Baseline seems to act differently.  I can not be the first person to ask to list the machines failed or succeed a Configuration Baseline or maybe I am the first to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that are possible via the built in cmdlets but some just are not (yet?). However it is almost always possible to get the same behavior the console has with wmi (because the console uses wmi itself)

To find out how it is good to know that there is a log file "SMSProv.log" that tells you what the console does for every dialog you open. It is located on the site server wherever you installed the ConfigMgr in a sub-folder Logs (so default would be %Program Files%\Microsoft Configuration Manager\Logs).

So if you use that when checking the deployment status of a baseline you will notice that it basically translates to 3 commands (All in the namespace

```
Root\SMS\site_<SiteCode>
```

on your siteserver):

```
SELECT * FROM SMS_DCMDeploymentCompliantAssetDetails WHERE AssignmentID=<AssignmentID>

SELECT * FROM SMS_DCMDeploymentNonCompliantAssetDetails WHERE AssignmentID=<AssignmentID>

SELECT * FROM SMS_DCMDeploymentErrorAssetDetails WHERE AssignmentID=<AssignmentID>
```

where AssignemtID is the ID you would get e.g. from

```
(Get-CMBaselineDeployment -Name "<Your Baslines Name>").AssignmentID
```

A little exception would be that the console filters the error further by error type but to me it seems like this is maybe not even what you want and you could easily do it in Powershell later if you need to.

The SQL command is also available in most cases in the SMSProv.log, and in some cases it leads to a faster execution. However in this one probably not really and it is a lot more complex most of the time.